# How to open a file the fast way in Gimp?

Tags: gimp

The classical way to open a file is not followed in [Gimp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIMP). There is no browse button, nor there is a textbox where one can paste the path to the file. I do not edit images everyday and I always have to loose half an hour to be able to open a simple file. So here are my questions:

1. How to open a file in Gimp the fast way (something akin to pasting the pathway on a textbox).
2. Is there a reason for the current state of affairs, or is it just the decision of some chief developer?

Answer (score 10):

This may be a restriction from our OS or our file browser integration with Gimp. With the Gtk-toolkit on a Linux (here Ubuntu) OS and in Windows we have several choices to quickly open images with Gimp 2.8.:

#### From the File browser:

1. Double click on an image to open with Gimp after we made it our default image editor.
2. Right click context menu *Open with... Gimp* on our file browser.
3. Drag & Drop on the Gimp window will load this image:

   [image]

#### From Gimp

4. *File > Open...* will open the Gtk file selector where we have the choice to browse or to enter a path:

   [image]
5. On *File > Open Location...* Gimp will open a textbox to enter a path:

   [image]
6. *File > Open Recent* will give us a dropdown menu of recently used files.

Comment: In `file/Open` the location bar may not show. If thatis teh case hit ctrl+L. The decision to hide it was not made by GIMP developers, rather it was pushed on them by the gtk+ project which GIMP depends on.

Comment: @jsbueno: yeah - good point. The OS fileselectors may differ considerably. Good that Gimp has alternatives in addition :)

Comment: @grokkaine: also, the key to working efficiently with files in GIMP is to add your image files to the file selector window in `1` - be sure to add your working directories to the list at left, clicking on the `+` icon at the leftmost position there.